# Postgresql Trigger to Set Columns to NULL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to use a trigger in Postgresql to "delete" data from specific columns (set to NULL), when a other column in the same relation is updated. This could look like this in the trigger function:

```sql
IF OLD.column_1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column_1 THEN
UPDATE relation_1 SET column_2 = NULL;
```

There already is a working trigger to delete data from other relations (see below). I'm not sure, if I can adapt the trigger function to my needs or if I need to implement a totally new trigger for that.

Current trigger and trigger function:

```sql
-- Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_results_trigger_function()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.column_1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column_1 THEN

        DELETE FROM relation_2
        WHERE relation_2_id IN (
            SELECT relation_2_id FROM peak
            WHERE relation_1 = OLD.relation_1_id
        );
    END IF;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$

-- Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER delete_results_on_event_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE
ON relation_1
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION delete_results_trigger_function();
```

The software using this database and the trigger writes at some point to the relation_1 updating several columns in this relation (e.g. column_2) including column_1 (which triggers the trigger function). I want the changes from the software to be written to the relation (not set to NULL). But when a update is made manually to relation_1.column_1 (e.g. set to NULL), the corresponding columns in relation_1 should be set to NULL as well.

I hope it is clear, what I want to do here.
Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Slightly offtopic: It looks like your current trigger could be replace by a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Hey @FrankHeikens thanks for your proposal. To use a foreign key constraint would be nice. I thought about that before the trigger implementation as well, but I didn't come up with an idea on how to implement that. I would need to add the relation_1.column_1 to relation_2. But relation_2 is not the only table to delete from (there are 2 more). This would cost me a lot of disk space and wouldn't fit the logic of my data quite well. But I'm open to your ideas - maybe I'm missing something!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of some columns in the same table and table row that made the trigger fire, you don't use `UPDATE` (that might well cause an infinite loop and it not very efficient even without that).

Instead, you define a `BEFORE` trigger that modifies `NEW` and return that modified row, which will then used as the new table row:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ... RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
   ...
   IF OLD.column_1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column_1
   THEN
      NEW.column_2 = NULL;
   END IF;
   ...
   RETURN NEW;
$$;
```

Change your current trigger into a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and make sure it returns `NEW`, then you can add that code to your current trigger.

Comment: Hey @laurenz, thanks for your proposal. Unfortunately with this implementation, the columns to update (e.g. relation_1.column_2) are all set to NULL. IF they are updated by a query, they should be set to that values. IF just relation_1.column_1 is updated without new values for the other columns, the columns should be set to NULL.

Comment: You mean, there is an `UPDATE`, but `column_1` is not modified by that `UPDATE`? Then define the trigger as `CREATE TRIGGER ... BEFORE UPDATE OF column_1 ON relation_1`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work out either. Maybe I described my problem not specifically enough. But I solved it with another approach. I put an additional IF clause inside the trigger function, which is not perfect, but does the job. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, seems the question was not clear enough. Perhaps you could write an answer with your solution? It might be interesting for others.

Comment: This is almost unreadable. Please write an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for my problem (more like a workaround):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ... ... $$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.column_1 IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.column_1 THEN
        DELETE FROM relation_2
        WHERE relation_2_id = OLD.column_1
        ;
    END IF;
    IF NEW.column_1 IS NULL THEN
        NEW.column_2 = NULL;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER ... 
BEFORE UPDATE OF column_1
ON relation_1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION delete_results_trigger_function()
;
```